# Unable to use my wrapper class in Lightning component API version 42

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, wrapper-class

**Below Code:**

```
public class parentclass{

    public class Model{
        @AuraEnabled public String year {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Map<Integer, Decimal> dataMap {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Component Code:**

```
<aura:component controller="parentclass" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="listVehicles" type="parentclass.Model[]" />
```

** Erorr while saving the component:

> Failed to save undefined: Invalid  type: Model[image][]`**

This is speacially on the API 42 version, I have old component which is on 40 API version works absolutely fine. Is this is a bug or not the right way to use wrapper any more in lightning ?

Any ideas appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are not supposed to use it as per this [link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips/units/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips_apex#Tdxn4tBK-heading4) from salesforce. This was never intended to work in the first place. This was enforced from Api version 42.

Use a separate outer class for the inner wrapper class.

Comment: Can you post this as separate question since this is not related to the original question.

Comment: sure, I will mark your as best answer, I will put that in separate questions